Entity Framework changes a field without my permission
I have a problem that Entity Framework changes the Adm and AdmId fields when I add a User entity in list user.
This is my table Room:
public class Room
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // um para muitos:
    [Required]
    public User Adm { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AdmId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; } = default;
    public string? Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    // um para muitos:
    public List<Message>? Messages { get; set; } = new List<Message>();

    // um para muitos:
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<User>? Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    public List<string>? UserName { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

This is my code for adding a new user in the room:
try
{
    participeData.Room.UserName.Add(participeData.User.Name);
    participeData.Room.Users.Add(participeData.User);

    participeData.User.RoomsNames.Add(participeData.Room.Name);
    participeData.User.Rooms.Add(participeData.Room);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

I'm trying to add a new user into of the room. The conflict is that Adm and AdmId fields are changed when I add the commands
participeData.Room.UserName.Add(participeData.User.Name);
participeData.Room.Users.Add(participeData.User);

participeData.User.RoomsNames.Add(participeData.Room.Name);
participeData.User.Rooms.Add(participeData.Room);


DetectChanges() will fixup references if the PK / FK values of tracked entities match. Are you adding a User with PK == default?

Does the added user happen to be the same as the one that is Adm?

I found the error. My db relationship config was wrong, when I changed the user in room the Adm was replaced with this user. This happening because of the db relationship.
